# gnuplot - changing the tics in pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot, colormap

Well, I am trying to plot a matrix-like data file using pm3d option as follows

```
set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
splot namefile matrix
```

I have tried to upload an image but it seems I don't have enough reputation. Ok, so the problem is that the data come from logarithmic binned x and y axes, but the default option for the tics separation is the lineal one (1, 2, 3, ... ). If I want to rescale the tics to another interval, it is easy as long as I keep this linearity ( e.g: 0, 10, 20,... ). However I would like to rescale them to my data interval but logarithmically separated (1, 10, 100,... ). Of course, what I only want to change are the tics, whereas the proportion within the plot is kept the same.

After thinking and looking around I could not find a satisfactory answer. Any hint on how to solve it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the tics, but not the scaling of the data you must manually set the tics like

```
set for [i=1:5] xtics add (sprintf('%.0f', 10**(i-1)) i)
set for [i=1:5] ytics add (sprintf('%.0f', 10**(i-1)) i)
```

Comment: Thank you @Christoph for your answer and sorry for my delay on giving the feedback. Your answer doesn't solve my problems. Probably I wasn't very clear. Trying again: My square matrix has several hundred of rows and columns. I know which's the upper value in the 'original' axes, say 5·10^7. My question is then, how do I set the tics spanning the whole axes while logarithmically separated in my range? I.e., the leftmost tic is 1 and the rightmost tic is 5·10^7, independent of number of rows or columns I have. Using your method, the first 5 tics are 'logarithmic' but the others still are lineal.

Comment: You can use a different upper limit for the iterations, e.g. `set for [i=0:10] ...`. If that still doesn't solve your problem, you should post an example image of your desired output.